# export json object from .json file to vue through express and assign it to the variable

Tags: json, express, vue.js

I would like to display on my page some data which I have in dsa.json file. I am using express with vue.

Here's my code from the server.js:

```
var data;
fs.readFile('./dsa.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => { 
  if (err) throw err;
  exports.data = data;
});
```

Here's code from between `<script>` tags in index.html

```
var server = require(['../server']);
var data = server.data;
var scoreboards = new Vue({
    el: '#scoreboard',
    data: {
        students: data
    }
});
```

I am using requirejs (CDN) to require server between `<script>` tags in index.html.

index.html is in public directory whereas dsa.json and server.js are in the main catalogue.

Here are the errors I get in the client:

```
require.min.js:1 GET http://localhost:3000/server.js 
require.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Script error for "../server"
```

I think it has something to do with context and scope but I don't know what exactly.

I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is completely wrong. You can't include the server script on your page. Also, I'm not a NodeJS ninja, yet I don't think that exporting the data inside the function will work -> `exports.data = data`.

The workaround:

Server side:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const data = fs.readFileSync('./dsa.json', 'utf8'); // sync is ok in this case, because it runs once when the server starts, however you should try to use async version in other cases when possible

app.get('/json', function(req, res){
  res.send(data);
});
```

Client side:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/json', true);
xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var scoreboards = new Vue({
    el: '#scoreboard',
    data: {
        students: JSON.parse(xhr.response)
    }
  });
});
xhr.addEventListener('error', function() {
  // handle error
});
xhr.send();
```